# Possible to use Aggregation Function on Caml Query?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Is it possible to group a sharepoint list and use aggregation functions?(sum, count etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

see: 
[GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093.aspx)
[Aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms468626%28v=office.12%29.aspx)